# Is it possible to abort a long running query using iBATIS?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I have a GUI which allows users to run long running queries. Sometimes, the users regret running the queries and would like to cancel them. The queries are running using iBATIS against an Oracle database, and I know that the java.sql.Statement interface defines a cancel method that might or might not be implemented by the driver. So my question is, is it possible to use iBATIS to invoke this method to cancel the query (given the right driver), or is there any other way of aborting an ongoing long running query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 
I guess that once the got to the DB server, cancelling it is really a "DB vendor specific" issue. 
If your requirement is to cancel the query, 
 when it comes to your application 
(i.e - if it reaches the Oracle DB server, and is run there, you are fine, as long as you will not get the result), consider using the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface which has a cancel method. 
You can [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) a "Callable" to run your query, and it will return a proper object of type which is an implementation. 
If you need to abort - just use the "cancel" method of the future object.
You can also check using "isCanceled" to see if submission was cancelled, and make proper treatment at your code.

Comment: I believe this is not supported by iBATIS, or is it?

Comment: This is plain java SE code. have your iBATIS calls wrapped with Callables and invoked using ExecutorService. We cancel this way queries to ldap servers (i.e - they may be invoked at the ldap server, we ignore the result this way)

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Do you have any code example one could look at?

Comment: Not with iBatis, but in general - I am a maintainer at engine-core part of oVirt open source project. Visit our website - www.ovirt.org and git clone the "engine" part. You can find ThreadPoolUtil.java ther e - you will see we use it with invokeAny for example, and return Future, then you will be able to find an example with the cancel() method in our code.